# Zustand 4 slices pattern with devtools and persist middlewares

Tags: reactjs, typescript, state, zustand

I am trying to use zustand 4 for my state management in my react & typescript project. I am attempting to use the slices pattern that has devtools and persist middlewares for the boundstore, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is the code so far

```
//store/slices/sliceOne.ts
import { StateCreator } from "zustand";
import { FormType } from "@/features/apply/schemas/form-1";
import { TBoundState, TMutators } from "@/store";

export type TSliceOne = {
  stateOne: FormType;
  setStateOne: (data: FormType) => void;
};

export const SliceOne: StateCreator<
  TBoundState,
  TMutators,
  [],
  TSlice
> = (set) => ({
  stateOne: {
    input_one: "",
    input_two: "",
    input_three: "",
    input_four: "",
    input_five: "",
    input_six: "",
  },
  setStateOne: (data) => set({ stateOne: data }),
});
```

```
//store/useBoundStore.ts
import { create } from "zustand";
import { persist, devtools } from "zustand/middleware";
import { TSliceOne, SliceOne } from "@/store";

export type TMutators = [
  ["zustand/devtools", never],
  ["zustand/persist", unknown]
];

export type TBoundState = TSliceOne;

export const useBoundStore = create<TBoundState>()(
  devtools(
    persist(
      (...initializer) => ({
        ...SliceOne(...initializer),
      }),
      { name: "bound-store" }
    )
  )
);
```

```
// store/index.ts
export * from "./useBoundStore";
export * from "./slices/sliceOne";
```

however in my browser i am getting the error
TypeError: (0 , *store__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0*_.SliceOne) is not a function
this error is being cause on ...SliceOne in useBoundStore

I followed the zustand docs as best as possible.
I am guessing it is an issue because setStateOne is taking in data from outside the state?